# Providing a function to override the default query

Tags: wp-query

In a plugin, I want to provide a function for users to set the default query in their templates, so they can use some custom loops. What would be the best way of doing it?

I imagine something like this:

```
my_plugin_set_query();
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ... iteration through a predefined post set ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, and it's working, but I'm not sure if it's the best way of doing it:

```
function get_override_query() {
    $posts = get_posts_from_some_custom_method();
    $query = new WP_Query();
    $query->current_post = -1;
    $query->post_count = count( $posts );
    $query->posts = $posts;        
    return $query;
}

function override_query() {
    global $wp_query;
    $query = get_override_query();
    $wp_query = $query;
}
```

Then, I can also iterate through posts without changing the default query, like:

```
$query = get_override_query();
while ( $query->has_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plug into the query, [`pre_get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is going to be your friend. [Pippin Williamson](http://pippinsplugins.com/using-pre_get_posts-modify-queries-meta-data-more/) also has a great writeup on the subject.

Comment: Actually, @Zach, I wanted something to be done in some template parts when the theme developer wants to. See the edit.